# ntop bug on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, ubuntu-14.04

I have ntop working on a Hyper-V virtual machine Ubuntu 14.04 with netflow plugin. Everything seems to be working well, but when I click on IP, then Traffic, I want to see each person on the network. Instead I get the spinning logo.

I was wondering if that's a bug or is there something I can do?

[image]

Comment: There is [discussion](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=75801.0) about this problem. I did not read entire thing but looks like it was resolved.

Comment: thanks i found another way by installing cacti and adding ntop as an addon works wonders :)